# When using ui-router normal href which point to element id don't work

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

I'm modifying our web to use ui-router for state change which works good. We have few href that points to the element id and they fail to work instead it routes to /. How to avoid it and have our existing href works parallelly?

```
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-parent="#accordion"
                    data-toggle="collapse" class="panel-toggle" href="#faq1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Can I viverra sit amet quam eget lacinia?</a></h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="faq1">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life
                        accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia
                        aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                        quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                        sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee
                        nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh
                        helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt
                        sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                        Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
                        aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
                        accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--//panel-->
```

Comment: what happens when the `href` is turned into a `ui-sref`?

Comment: no luck with ui-sref.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to add the anchor routes to your angular routing and then make sure the `#blah` part ends up being appended to the route as a query parameter.

see [angularjs ui-router query parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters)